# Virtual Box installed from the repos does not seem to be able to run with 3d acceleration

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu, hardware-acceleration

I'm running with Kubuntu 18.04 as host, on a machine with a Intel HD chip. Virtual Box is installed from the repos and guest is Kubuntu 17.10. If I do not enable hw acceleration, everything works properly, but it is considerable slow. If I turn graphics acceleration on, I get the result shown in the image. No mouse interaction is possible. Any idea what I should change to make it work properly with acceleration?

[image]

EDIT: This happens now after installing proprietary drivers in the guest (kubuntu asked me if I wanted to install virtual box drivers). It seems now it is hardware accelerated and the mouse interaction is ok. But the plasma desktop is above the other windows and wrong geometry.

[image]

Comment: Did you install the guest additions too?

Comment: Have you installed  Virtualbox extension pack on the host `virtualbox-ext-pack` and Guest addition in the Guest `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso`

Comment: I installed guest additions by using the "Install guest additions" item in the menu, which mounted the cdrom, and I installed virtualbox-ext-pack in the host.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the problem with VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host, with a Kubuntu 18.04.1 guest. Apt-upgraded and with guest additions installed.

It seems that it is a VirtualBox issue, that is not likely to be resolved any soon.

So the only workaround that I have found is to:

1. Shut down the VM and disable the 3D acceleration in the VM's settings in the VirtualBox UI. This should solve the problem, but the display performance is horrible, because (in my understanding) virtual box is emulating a 3D accelerator using the CPU, and Plasma uses an OpenGL renderer on top of that.
2. In KDE's system settings app, go to *Display and Monitor -> Compositor*. Change *Rendering Backend* to *XRender*. Apply.[image: screenshot of the settings app]

This tells Plasma to use 2D rendering. For me it works well enough, windows move smoothly enough, there is no noticeable lag, scrolling a web page for example is also relatively smooth.

Of course, if you actually need 3D rendering for other apps, then you have a real problem.